# EWS managed API issue

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

EWS managed API is not able fetch attendees for added Exchange resources in meeting when resources added in Window outlook .

Trying to find all added attendees in meeting using EWS managed API . When Exchange rooms (resource) are added meeting OWA and Mac outlook , EWS managed API is able to get all exchange rooms as attendee
but when same rooms are added as attendee in native Window Outlook , EWS managed API is not able find all Exchange rooms as attendee .

Comment: Could you be more specific? What code have you tried so far?

Comment: PropertySet PropertySetToLoad = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties); PropertySetToLoad.Add(AppointmentSchema.Organizer); PropertySetToLoad.Add(AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees); PropertySetToLoad.Add(AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees); PropertySetToLoad.Add(AppointmentSchema.Resources); Appointment _appointment = Appointment.Bind(exchangeService, Appointment.Id, PropertySetToLoad);

Comment: Did you try to save the item after making changes in Outlook for Windows?

Comment: Yes, here meeting is being created in native Outlook for Windows with multiple exchange rooms added as attendee.